# why are promise libraries (ie. bluebird) deprecating the deferred pattern in favor of the Promise constructor?

Tags: javascript

And, in the same vein, why do promise libraries typically not provide a `resolve()` and `reject()` method on the promise itself, bypassing the need for a deferred object?

EDIT

OK, I understand and accept the importance of throw safety.

Additionally... I have been using promises in an eventually-resolved callback scenario which seems to require the defer pattern. That is, I have a class which will eventually be loaded with data and which exposes a promise as way to "listening" for the "loaded" event.  The client will need to gain access to that callback-promise before any asynchronous activity has even begun.  In this case, I use defer to generate a resolvable promise.  Does this sound legit?  Any suggestions for a better approach?

Comment: I suppose it is because the promise constructor won, the libraries align with ES6.

Comment: Bluebird's [deprecated APIs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/deprecated_apis.md) docs says it is "it is much more awkward and error-prone than using new Promise" - but maybe there's a more detailed discussion somewhere.

Comment: @elclanrs - if the reason is "to align with es6", why not deprecate the entire library?

Comment: @Amit: Why not deprecate lodash, after all `forEach` has been around since ES5. The reason is because these libraries add more functionality and focus on performance.

Comment: @elclanrs  - 1st, I'm not the one who suggested the reason is related to ES6, you did, so maybe you can suggest the same logical answer to your lodash question. 2nd, lodash functions, including forEach are much more versatile, for example iterating objects. 3rd, you don't need a whole new promise implementation in order to add functionality, you only need to enable that functionality on top of native promises, but I guess that's simply not the reason

Comment: @elclanrs: Do you know *why* the promise constructor won ES6?

Comment: @Bergi: No idea, I wished the API was a bit different, but that's what we got now...

Comment: @elclanrs: Go look at the duplicate then (and earn Benjamin another upvote :-))

Comment: @elclanrs: Just curious, what did you wish to be different?

Comment: @Bergi: perhaps the overloading of `.map` and `.flatMap` into `.then`, I would have kept them separate. I'm not convinced of the benefits...

Comment: @elclanrs: Oh, right, I'm totally with you there (though I [call them `map` and `chain`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land)); I thought you'd wanted to change the promise construction pattern